# Swift 3 - Firebase: Won´t save to database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have problem with current app. When I want to save into Firebase database is nothing happen. I can´t find my error and it won´t even print out "Failed to save post to DB". Can someone find my error? I´m not so good at programming and Swift 3... This code have I copied from another project that I have and it works there so I´m really confused...? Help would be appreciated!

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import MapKit

class MapAddPostHeader: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

var locationData: CLLocation!
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

 lazy var sharePositionButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Plus_Unseleted"), for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleShare), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button

}()

func handleShare() {


    self.sendToDatabase()

}

fileprivate func sendToDatabase() {
    guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else { return }
    guard let locationdata = locationData else { return }

    let userPositionRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("position").child(uid)
    let ref = userPositionRef.childByAutoId()
    let timestamp = NSNumber(value: Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970))
    let fromId = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    let values = ["latitude" : (locationdata.coordinate.latitude), "longitude" : (locationdata.coordinate.longitude), "fromId" : fromId ?? "", "timestamp" : timestamp] as [String : Any]
    ref.updateChildValues(values) { (err, ref) in

        if let err = err {
            print("Failed to save post to DB", err)
            return
        }

        print("Successfully saved position to DB")

    }

}
```

Comment: In the `sendToDatabase()` function you have this line `guard let locationdata = locationData else { return }`. Does `locationData` have a value? Because if `locationData` is not defined the function will not run any further

Comment: The `locationData` has no value can I see now... I´m not really sure how I´m going to solve this yet...